New internal package shows in the menu, but default Turborepo package does not — why?


I added an internal package to my Next.js project built with Turborepo, following guide. After running the project, the new package appears in the left menu, is it ok?
However, the default package created by Turborepo doesn’t show in the menu. Is this behavior expected? If not, what could be causing the new internal package to appear in the menu?

If your new internal package has a start script in its package.json file, it will appear in the terminal when you run pnpm dev. To prevent this, simply remove the start script, and it will no longer be displayed.
